# TeamCity Build - MSB3644: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v7.0 were not found

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, teamcity, .net-7.0

I have a TeamCity Build Config that I have updated from the "Microsoft Visual Studio solution (.sln) runner" to use a ".Net Runner" msbuild command to build my API solution.
Previously the Build Config Template this is based on was used to build a .Net Framework 4.8 or so web api but now I have written a new .Net 7 api in a new repo which is linked correctly to this Build Config.
When i get to the Build step to Build the solution I'm getting the following error:

4>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.201\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1177,5): error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v7.0 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks

This error says I should install "Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack)" but i have all the following installed on the build server.

[build server .net related installs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1mKn.png)

Maybe i am wrong but i have not found any "Targeting Pack" for .Net 7, these seem to finish with .Net Framework and the SDK for .Net 7 has been installed as you can see in the image.

I have also installed "Visual Studio Build Tools 2022" to add to the previously installed "Visual Studio Build Tools 2017/2019".

The reference in the error message to "sdk\3.1.201" this was the latest version of .Net installed until very recently and no other builds/apps have referenced a later version than that until now. I'm not sure where this path is coming from as I have "overridden" all the "Build Configuration Parameters" that reference this "3.1.201" value to use "7.0.403" but the path remains the same.

Any help or advice/guidance would really be appreciated, thanks in advance.

I have googled the error message and most of the answers seems to reference .Net Framework versions.
I have tried to override the paths that reference this older .Net Core version 3.1.201.
I have installed the latest Build tools as was suggested from one of the similar issues i found online.

Comment: Is there a [global.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json) file in the source code that could still be pointing to 3.1.201?

Comment: ".NETFramework,Version=v7.0" does not exist.  Happens when msbuild simply doesn't recognize the target version, be sure to have the 7.0 SDK installed and that you are using an up-to-date version of msbuild.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the responses and for the record, there was no global.json file in my solution and I couldnt find any other global.json file so I created my own at the root of my solution and this resolved the issue. So its now building with the correct version, thanks again.